# How to find the volume

Tags: integration

Find the volume generated by revolving the region bounded by $$xy= 4$$ $$y= \left ( x-3 \right )^{2}$$  about the x-axis.
I really need help. Thanks

Comment: Revolving about what?

Comment: The X-axis, sir.. Sorry, I edited it..

Comment: First you'll want to find the points of intersection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we need to make a reasonably good sketch. The hyperbola and parabola meet at $x=4$, and at $x=1$. There is a double root at $x=1$, so the hyperbola and parabola are tangent there. Graphing software or a graphing calculator may be a useful aid.

The finite region between the two curves lies between $x=1$ and $x=4$. In that interval, the parabola is below the hyperbola.

Imagine a cross-section of the solid, perpendicular to the $x$-axis, "at" $x$. The cross-section is a disk with a disk cut out of it. The outer radius is given by $y$, where $y=\frac{4}{x}$. The inner radius is $(3-x)^2$.

So the area of cross-section is $\pi\left(\frac{16}{x^2}-(x-3)^4\right)$, and therefore the volume is
$$\int_{x=1}^4  \pi\left(\frac{16}{x^2}-(x-3)^4\right)\,dx.$$

Comment: sir, is your answer infinity?

Comment: By the way, I had a typo, it is $4/x$, not $1/x$. The volume is finite. You can compute it (with the detypoed formula), and I will tell you whether I agree. Please give the answer as $k\pi$, no decimals.

Comment: I will need to be away for a while, so here are numbers for you to check your work against. $\int_1^4\frac{16}{x^2}\,dx=12$ and $\int_1^4 (x-3)^4\,dx=\frac{33}{5}$. (There are opportunities for minus sign errors here.)  So we end up with $\pi(12-33/5$, which is $\frac{27\pi}{5}$.